# get title from heading tag

Tags: javascript, html

```
for(i=0;i<headingsallowed.length;i++){
    var x=allhtml.getElementsByTagName(headingsallowed[i]);

}
```

I have this code which gets all the headings in my scripts, I want to process them one by one and output the title that is in each of the headings. `headingsallowed` is the array with the headings in so just ['h1,'h2','h3']. `allhtml` is just `var allhtml = document.getElementById('content');`
SO

```
<h1>hi</h1>
<h1>he</h1>
<h1>yes</h1>
<h1>no</h1>
```

would output `hi,he,yes,no`

I tried `x.innerHTML` and `x.text` but they did not work

Comment: How did you try `innerHTML`? And did you try `innerhtml` or `innerHTML`?

Comment: what is `headingsallowed` here?

Comment: edited my question. I did use innerHTML

Comment: What is `allhtml` here?

Comment: Please give whole code you have tried so far

Comment: Where is `'content'`?

Comment: I don't get a reason for using variable like `allHTML` and `headingsAlowed`. If any reason you should mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given html, the following will print the content inside each heading.

```
var headings = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
 for(i=0;i<headings.length;i++){
  console.log(headings[i].innerHTML); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem properly. I got this working.

HTML

```
<h1>hi</h1>
<h1>he</h1>
<h1>yes</h1>
<h1>no</h1>
```

Javascript

```
var allHeadings=document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
for(i=0;i<allHeadings.length;i++){console.log(allHeadings[i].innerHTML)}
```